# When did merged Namecoin-Bitcoin mining start?

Tags: namecoin, merged-mining

(This question was originally asked before merged mining began)

When exactly did merged mining of Bitcoin and Namecoin chains start?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The switch to merged mining is [scheduled for Namecoin block 19200](http://dot-bit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=217).  At the time of this writing, the Namecoin network is on block 18805, so 395 more blocks need to be solved.

The last 29 blocks on the [Namecoin block explorer](http://explorer.dot-bit.org/) were solved in an average of 108.79 minutes each.  Extrapolating from this, 395 blocks should be solved in just under 30 days, so sometime around September 29th.

Comment: Only 43 blocks to go, A couple of days at the current rate.

Comment: We're at block 19202. So, any early reports of merged mining in the wild?

Comment: Namecoin blocks are being generated about every 5.5 minutes right now.